# Can I use cloud run with self-hosted/private docker image registry?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-cloud-run

When I deployed with my self-hosted(private) Docker image registry, got this error:

```sh
This service will require authentication to be invoked.
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [serverless-functions-go] in project [PROJECT_ID] region [us-central1]
X Deploying new service...
  . Creating Revision...
  . Routing traffic...
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.deploy) Invalid image provided in the revision template. Expected [region.]gcr.io/repo-path[:tag or @digest], obtained dtr.artifacts.xxx.com/xxxxx/xxxx/serverless-functions-go:latest
```

Before pulling the image from my private docker image registry, I need to use the command like:

```sh
docker login [options]
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can I use cloud run with private docker container registry?

No, not at this time. See ["Images you can deploy"](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#images) in the Cloud Run documentation.

Comment: Update the question. So there is no command like `docker login` to pull the image from the private registry when using `gcloud beta run deploy` command?

Comment: @slideshowp2 - The documentation is clear that you must use Google Container Registry. For the command `docker login` the Docker credentials are stored on your desktop.There is no method to transfer those credentials into the management system that runs/deploys Cloud Run.